# How to use AWS Windows ec2 instance in fedora?

Tags: amazon-ec2, fedora-25

I am trying to connect aws Windows ec2 instance from Fedora 25, I connect it on windows machine without any issue as Windows has mstsc by default but this time I used below command on fedora-25 to connect to windows ec2 instance:

```
rdesktop -u administrator ec2-35-144-210-177.ap-south1.compute.amazonaws.com 
###failed after 2 mins
```

> I got below error -  ERROR:
>   ec2-35-144-210-177.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com: unable to connect

I am able to connect ec2 windows instance from windows machine using mstsc but not able to connect from fedora as rdesktop is not working as expected. Any Suggestion to resolve this issue?

Comment: "I am trying to use aws Windows ec2 from Fedora 25"  : Please explain  meaning of "use" . Do you mean "connect" , or do you mean load another OS in it ?

Comment: I have updated my questions if there is any confusion, I am trying to connect to aws windows ec2 instance from fedora but not able to connect as rdesktop is not working as expected.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/592582/unable-to-connect-to-remote-desktop

Comment: @mootmoot - Thanks for looking into this issue I tried remmina tool but it didn't work for me, Not sure what was the issue but I deleted old windows ec2 from aws and created new ec2 and it worked for me with same command. I will research on it and share my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly mistake and Below is my finding on this issue, consider this scenario-

```
laptop1 - running on Windows10 - connected to network1
laptop2 - running on fedora25  - connected to network2
```

aws Instance was created from windows10 with network1 that is why inbound rules of security group by default create an entry and it will allow network1 to connect to Windows ec2 instant without any issue.

> In my Situation -

```
From the error - unable to connect, it is difficult to find out the root cause.
```

> I created Windows ec2 instance from Windows10 which was running on
>   network1 but I was trying to access from fedora25 which is running on
>   network2, network1 is different from network2 and if you want to
>   connect from a network which is different from the network which you
>   used to create Windows ec2 instance then you need to create one more
>   entry in the security group for inbound Rules to add the ip address of your current network. And when I deleted the
>   old machine and created new machine from fedora25+network2 it worked
>   because by default it created one inbound rule in the Security Group
>   for network2.

Comment: Well, this reminds me of those helpdesk that pulling out a long checklist.